# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in ..?

Tags: php, mysql, message

The line where this error was called from is this:

> $celkova_suma=mysql_result($c_res, 0,
>   0)+mysql_result($d_res, 0,
>   0)-$zlava_suma+$arr[$_POST['sp_platby']];

Can someone tell me what I should be looking for??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `[var_dump()](http://www.php.net/var_dump) on each of the parts of your equation and you'll probably find out that one of them is an array or an object, not a string or integer.